# Getting mean of variables in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am running .mean() on my data in python pandas but that is returning only the key on which i am grouping and the mean of the required column. I want all the columns, with the mean replacing the original values.
Have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work out. Below is the code i am using to generate means

```
dd1=df.groupby(['key']).agg({'sales':"mean"}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Give an example of your data. What are the columns, what is the data in columns, what do you expect as a result.

Comment: Why do you want to replace the original values? Just apply `.mean()` to the dataframe and you should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [**`transform`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation)... not [**`agg`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation)

```
dd1 = df.groupby('key').transform('mean')
```

---

[*Minimal and Complete Verifiable Example **MCVE***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(10, 4)
).add_prefix('C').assign(key=np.random.choice(list('AB'), 10))
print(df)

         C0        C1        C2        C3 key
0 -0.239780  0.167832  0.879349  0.643696   A
1  0.517747  0.573424 -0.480853 -0.162014   A
2  0.236032 -0.396924 -1.406381  1.197946   A
3  0.479451 -0.790073  0.219239 -0.157358   B
4 -0.605864 -0.461622 -1.427521 -1.709760   B
5 -0.281919 -0.965817  1.256316 -1.351529   A
6 -2.085293  0.954725 -1.744391 -1.069667   A
7 -2.100504 -1.161964 -1.102306  0.547207   B
8  1.808283 -0.728799 -1.763971 -1.221539   B
9 -0.975264  0.958484 -0.458139  1.796640   B
```

Now `transform`

```
dd1 = df.groupby('key').transform('mean')
print(dd1)

         C0        C1        C2        C3
0 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
1 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
2 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
3 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
4 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
5 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
6 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
7 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
8 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
9 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
```

---

You can limit this to just a few columns by:

```
cols = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']
dd1 = df.groupby('key')[cols].transform('mean')
print(dd1)

         C0        C1        C2        C3
0 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
1 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
2 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
3 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
4 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
5 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
6 -0.370642  0.066648 -0.299192 -0.148313
7 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
8 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
9 -0.278780 -0.436795 -0.906540 -0.148962
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. But is there a way to get the mean of only a few variable, and not all? My dataframe has a set of catagorical variables as well

Comment: I am running python 2.6.6 and that gives me the below error - ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (15,11) . Is this due to the python version issue?

Comment: @AkshatAgrawal It might be... I'm not sure.  As for limiting it to just a few columns, see updated post.

Comment: @AkshatAgrawal don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem